# Storing data of different types c++

Tags: c++, types

I am working on a modular data logger that allows one to log data of different types. At the moment I made a File class that is a template. In order to declare an object of such a class one would do as such: `File<double> f("filename.txt")` or `File<float> f("filename.txt")`. I want to be able to store objects that were declared with `double` or `float` as template parameters in one vector. Is it possible to do something like that? I have tried a method online that uses a union as such:

```
union typ {
    int int_dat;
    double double_dat;
    float float_dat;
}
```

and allows me to declare a vector as such: `vector<File<typ> >`. However, this gives me linker errors. Is there a easier, cleaner way to attempt this? The entire project in question is [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?c72jy9gj2j72yaz)

EDIT: follow up to this. How would one circumvent the issue surrounding the fact that if I conduct such operations:

```
std::vector<File<typ> > files;

File<typ> f("test.txt");
files.push_back(f);
files.at(0) << 35.4;
```

it causes a compile time error which I comprehended as what I'm guessing is: 35.4 is not of the type typ and cannot be used in the operation `<<`. How would one bypass such an error?

Comment: What is the linker error?

Comment: It had something to do with the destructor. It's fixed now.

Comment: Add constructors to `union typ` that take each of the possible members, then it should be able to convert 35.4 to an instance of your union. You may have to add wrapping code eg `<< typ(35.4)`. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think your vector of unions might have some issues.  I haven't looked at your full code, but refer to this:

[Questions about vector, union, and pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786066/questions-about-vector-union-and-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work (see http://codepad.org/TyrURyar)

```
#include <vector>

union type {
    int int_dat;
    double double_dat;
    float float_dat;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T t;
};

void foo2() {
    std::vector<Foo<type> >  x;    
    // NOTE: In pre-C++11, space is required between the >'s
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I screwed around a bit with my code, and it turns out that it was actually a problem with my destructor. weird. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Boost::Variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html), if you can. It's a cleaner option. Unions can be used, but you should write and read from the same member [if you don't want to end up with undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c) i.e. it involves book keeping, which anyways Variant does for you automatically.

Comment: I do not usually use Boost... but... it is probably the more efficient option if you are dealing with a lot of data.

Comment: I would use this, but I have a small amount of memory to work with, so I do not have the liberty to use external libraries.